# How to determine the input impedance of an inverting amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, impedance, inverting-amplifier

How do I determine the input impedance of the op amp in the given circuit?

Mind you, the input impedance of the op-amp and not the circuit itself.

I have data on the input voltage and the output voltage. Is there a formula I could use involving output and input voltage to calculate the same?

[image]

Comment: Which input? circuit or OA? and why do you need to know the Zin for Vin- of OP AMP if it is so much higher than the 1K.

Comment: The input impedance of the opamp is given on the data sheet. Typically more than 100 megohms. For an ideal opamp the input impedance is infinity.

Comment: Include the picture here, please. Don't make us go to another site.

Comment: Assume the Zin of a low-noise bipolar opamp is 10pF (bipolar base-emitter and base-collector capacitances) in parallel with superBeta transistors operating at 100uA with Beta of 10,000. The Rin is beta/gm; gm at 1ma is 0.039 amp/volt; at 100uA, gm is 0.0039, and the reac is 1/0.0039 or 260 ohms. Scale 260 ohms by 10,000 and the Rin is 2.6Million ohms. Thus for a bipolar, using cascodes to avoid Miller effect, you may expect 10pF and 2.6Million ohms at each of Vin+ and Vin-.

Answer (score 0):

I think the impedance of the minus input of this OpAmp is for all practical purpose is infinite.  Meaning there is no current flowing into the minus input of the OpAmp.  Incoming Voltage causes current in the 2 k Ohm (the feedback) resistor.  (the gain of the OpAmp.{with negative feedback} causes both inputs to be at the same voltage, in this case zero Volts)